# Update UI after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am new to `knocokout.js` so i have a table in which data is bind using ajax call.When user click on edit button row information is fill to a form which is on same page below the table. 
after ajax call which update the data into database successfully , i am not able to show the changed value of particular object  which is changed into table. If i refresh then its show new value .

**Here is my html and js code .**

```
<div id="body">
        <h2>
            Knockout CRUD Operations with ASP.Net Form App</h2>
        <h3>
            List of Products</h3>
        <table id="products1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Id">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Category">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-bind="click: $root.edit">
                            Edit</button>
                        <button data-bind="click: $root.delete">
                            Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Total :
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: formatCurrency($root.Total())">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br />
        <div style="border-top: solid 2px #282828; width: 430px; height: 10px">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="if: Product">
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Update Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="productId" data-bind="visible: false">
                    ID</label>
                <label data-bind="text: Product().Id, visible: false">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">
                    Name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Name" type="text" title="Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category">
                    Category</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Category" type="text" title="Category" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">
                    Price</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Price" type="text" title="Price" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.update">
                    Update</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.cancel">
                    Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Code

```
    function formatCurrency(value) {
        return "$" + parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }

    function ProductViewModel() {

        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;
        //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
        self.Id = ko.observable("");
        self.Name = ko.observable("");
        self.Price = ko.observable("");
        self.Category = ko.observable("");

        var Product = {
            Id: self.Id,
            Name: self.Name,
            Price: self.Price,
            Category: self.Category
        };

        self.Product = ko.observable();
        self.Products = ko.observableArray(); // Contains the list of products

        // Initialize the view-model
        $.ajax({
            url: 'SProduct.aspx/GetAllProducts',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                // debugger;

                $.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {

                    self.Products.push(prd);
                })
                //Put the response in ObservableArray
            }
        });

        // Calculate Total of Price After Initialization
        self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            var arr = self.Products();
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sum += arr[i].Price;
            }
            return sum;
        });


        // Edit product details
        self.edit = function (Product) {
            self.Product(Product);

        }

        // Update product details
        self.update = function () {
            var Product = self.Product();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'SProduct.aspx/Update',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: "{Product:" + ko.toJSON(Product) + "}",
                success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data.d);                        
                      self.Product(null);

                    alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })

        }



        // Cancel product details
        self.cancel = function () {
            self.Product(null);

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

**and my webmethod which called by ajax request is as follow :**

```
// to update product
    [WebMethod]
    public static testModel.Product Update(testModel.Product Product)
    {
        testEntities db = new testEntities();
        var obj = db.Products.First(o => o.Id == Product.Id);
        obj.Name = Product.Name;
        obj.Price = Product.Price;
        obj.Category = Product.Category;

        db.SaveChanges();


        return obj;
    }
```

and JSON response of ajax call as follow

```
{"d":{"__type":"testModel.Product","Id":31,"Name":"12","Category":"12","Price":1350,"EntityState":2,"EntityKey":
{"EntitySetName":"Products","EntityContainerName":"testEntities","EntityKeyValues":
[{"Key":"Id","Value":31}],"IsTemporary":false}}}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a note to make it work with observable properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's happening.  Here: `self.Products.push(prd)` prd is just a plain javascript object with plain property values, nothing is observable.  You're pushing the raw object onto the Products observableArray, which updates the DOM because Products was changed and KO is watching it.  When you click 'edit', you set `self.Product` to that plain object and the KO updates the DOM with this object and its values because Product was changed and KO is watching it.  So now your Product form below displays, you see the information, and it looks like you can edit the properties but KO won't update those property changes because KO isn't watching them.  They're not observable.  Change:

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
  //self.Products.push(prd);
  self.Products.push({
    Id: ko.observable(prd.Id),
    Name: ko.observable(prd.Name),
    Price: ko.observable(prd.Price),
    Category: ko.observable(prd.Category)
  });
});
```

---

General helpful tips

---

```
<div data-bind="if: Product">
```

<strike>This only evaluates once when you bind the viewModel to the DOM with ko.applyBindings.  Since `self.Product` has an initial value of `null` KO removes this  altogether.</strike>*Note: I was thinking of @if for some reason.

This works like the visible binding except when the value is false, the element and its children are removed from the DOM.  So there is more DOM manipulation going on than necessary.  You probably just want to hide this `<div>`

I would recommend changing this to:

```
<div data-bind="visible: Product">
```

---

Instead of this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="text: Product().Name" />
<input type="text" data-bind="text: Product().Category" />
<input type="text" data-bind="text: Product().Price" />
```

Try this instead:

```
<div data-bind="with: Product">
  <input type="text" data-bind="text: Name" />
  <input type="text" data-bind="text: Category" />
  <input type="text" data-bind="text: Price" />
</div>
```

---

Consider renaming `self.Product` to `self.SelectedProduct` to make it more clear what it is for.

---

I'm not sure what this is doing in the ViewModel:

```
//Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
self.Id = ko.observable("");
self.Name = ko.observable("");
self.Price = ko.observable("");
self.Category = ko.observable("");

var Product = {
    Id: self.Id,
    Name: self.Name,
    Price: self.Price,
    Category: self.Category
};
```

You don't use them in the DOM.  You were kind of on the right path with this though.  Instead, before the ProductViewModel, create this:

```
function ProductModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};
  self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  self.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
  self.Category = ko.observable(data.Category);
}
```

Now instead of:

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
  self.Products.push({
    Id: ko.observable(prd.Id),
    Name: ko.observable(prd.Name),
    Price: ko.observable(prd.Price),
    Category: ko.observable(prd.Category)
  });
});
```

We can just do this:

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
  self.Products.push(new ProductModel(prd));
});
```

Hopefully that will get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I have used this `<div data-bind="if: Product">` because i want to show that update form when Product have value(user click on edit button ). Does this solve the problem of not changing value in UI  ?

Comment: I edited that piece as I misspoke about the 'if' binding.  I apologize as my answer is a mixed bag of helpful hints and an answer.  Let me edit my answer to put the solution at the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is something to change:

Replace

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
     self.Products.push(prd);
 })
```

With:

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
     self.Products.push({
                    Id: ko.observable(prd.Id),
                    Name: ko.observable(prd.Name),
                    Price: ko.observable(prd.Price),
                    Category: ko.observable(prd.Category)
                });
})
```

Use `ko.observable` to make your properties notify the view of its changes so that the view can update accordingly. This should work but not perfect because this is 2 way binding, so whenever you update the values in your `div`, the view model object is updated ***immediately*** and even if your ajax fails to update the data in backend, making the data out of synch between client side and server side.

For better solution. You need to have a look at [protectedObservable](https://gist.github.com/danieleli/1518403)

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
         self.Products.push({
                        Id: ko.protectedObservable(prd.Id),
                        Name: ko.protectedObservable(prd.Name),
                        Price: ko.protectedObservable(prd.Price),
                        Category: ko.protectedObservable(prd.Category)
                    });
    })
```

Inside your `self.update` ajax success function, trigger a change:

```
success: function (data) {
    var product =self.Product();   
    product.Id.commit();
    product.Name.commit();
    product.Price.commit();
    product.Category.commit();     
    self.Product(null);

    alert("Record Updated Successfully");
}
```

And revert if there is error:

```
error: function (data) {
    product.Id.reset();
    product.Name.reset();
    product.Price.reset();
    product.Category.reset(); 
 }
```

***Update:***
Remember to change all the places with `Product.Property` to `Product.Property()` to get its property value . For example:  `arr[i].Price` should be changed to `arr[i].Price()`

Answer (score -1):

Add `self.Products.push(data.d);` to the `update()` functions `success` handler.

```
success: function (data) {
     console.log(data.d);                        
     self.Product(null);

     self.Products.push(data.d);

     alert("Record Updated Successfully");
},
```

You need to update the array so that it reflects in bound html.

Comment: this will add new product instead of updating existing one.

Comment: Similar logic applies, update the `Product` in the `Products` array with the new data.